# Unable to use "createdb" in cartridge

Tags: django, python-2.7, mezzanine, cartridge

While trying to set up a Cartridge project, I came to the point of creating a database. Here is what I got:

```
(tezt1)16:06 ~/rifleShop $ python manage.py createdb --noinput
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    from settings import PROJECT_ROOT, PROJECT_DIRNAME
  File "/home/sanjivj/rifleShop/settings.py", line 437, in <module>
    set_dynamic_settings(globals())
  File "/home/sanjivj/.virtualenvs/tezt1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mezzanine/utils/conf.py", line 49, in se
t_dynamic_settings
    add_to_builtins("mezzanine.template.loader_tags")
  File "/home/sanjivj/.virtualenvs/tezt1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1405, in 
add_to_builtins
    builtins.append(import_library(module))
  File "/home/sanjivj/.virtualenvs/tezt1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1341, in 
import_library
    (taglib_module, e))
django.template.base.InvalidTemplateLibrary: ImportError raised loading mezzanine.template.loader_tags: cannot import name find_template_loader
```

In case it matters, this was on Pythonanywhere, but I got the same result on my laptop, working offline. Also, I did **not** get this problem with a "plain" Mezzanine project; only with Cartridge.

Answer (score 4):

You're using incompatible versions of Django and Mezzanine.

The current Mezzanine release only supports Django versions earlier than 1.7 - if you need Django 1.7 or later, try installing Mezzanine's source directly from Github, which supports 1.7 and greater.

Note: You can substitute "Mezzanine" above, with "Mezzanine and Cartridge".

Comment: Mezzanine 4.0.1 says it supports Django 1.7-1.8 but includes a few things which are deprecated, sadly.

Comment: 4.1 is just around the corner (in fact you could install from GitHub to get it before being released), and while supporting Django 1.9, it has also had a ton of work on removing use of deprecated Django features.


Please try it out: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mezzanine-users/b78FTSweFHo